# Difference between env.TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME and system.teamcity.projectName

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity there are two variables containing same value: `env.TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME` and `system.teamcity.projectName`. Is there a difference between these? Or something like that (deprecated, recommended)? In documentation I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [TeamCity Server Build Properties](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Predefined+Build+Parameters) its the same.

But `TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME` is Environment Variable.

The Environment Varialbe Feature was added in [2007](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-1643#comment=27-2050) to make it possible to pass build file full name as system property to the build.